# How to convert list to nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a nested dicts based the lists bellow.

```
assets = ["GOOG", "AMZN"]

variables=['LastTradePrice','Spread','QTD']

c = ['0']
```

I tried the code bellow, but it is missing some information and resulting on a short dict, with only one asset and one variable, I expected 2 assets as 'main keys' and 3 variables as 'sub keys', each 'sub key' followed by 0 as value.

**Tried this code:**

```
dct = {x: {str(y): str(z)} for x, y, z in zip(assets,variables,c)}
```

**Result I got:**

```
{'GOOG':{'LastTradePrice':'0'}}
```

***Expected Result:***

```
{'GOOG':{'LastTradePrice': '0','Spread':'0','QTD':'0'}, 'AMZN': {'LastTradePrice':'0','Spread':'0','QTD':'0'}}
```

Comment: `{k:{v:c[0] for v in variables} for k in assets}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
res = {x: dict(zip(variables, c * len(variables))) for x in assets}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'GOOG': {'LastTradePrice': '0', 'Spread': '0', 'QTD': '0'}, 'AMZN': {'LastTradePrice': '0', 'Spread': '0', 'QTD': '0'}}
```

Comment: Do you care to explain why it was wrong, and what you changed? For learning purposes.

Comment: because of `zip(assets,variables,c)`. just print `list(zip(assets,variables,c))` you will see. your code will work only if all `assets`, `variables` and `c` of same length